# freenom API not authenticating

Tags: node.js, api, dns, credentials

I want to automatically update Freenom's DNS record to my current global IP address  because I don't have a static IP. So I looked into Freenom's API and gave it a go. I tried this: `https://api.freenom.com/v2/domain/list?email=*****&password=*******`
and was expecting a list of active domains. But instead got this error back:

```
{
    "error": "Login credentials do not match any account",
    "status": "error"
}
```

Which is odd because I have checked the credentials and they are 100% correct. Instead of the `email` property I also tried a `username` property and I tried setting this information through HTTP headers and through the body, but I got nothing.

If anyone knows how I can get the API to work, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](https://my.freenom.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=19) the Freenom API is only available for resellers. I ran into the same issue myself. You can use a program that accesses the Freenom UI to change the DNS records, like [this one](https://github.com/maxisoft/Freenom-dns-updater), which uses Python and the UI to update DNS records. Or you can use another DNS provider, which is what I did.

Comment: Oh well that foils all plans I had of making use of this great site :/

Comment: @Jacob You could use a DNS provider with Freenom but I understand if you don't want to go that way... I am using Cloudflare myself and it has a publicly accessible API for updating my IP.

Comment: I ended up finding [this](https://github.com/maxisoft/Freenom-dns-updater). It needed some work but I fixed it, all that was left to do was run it recursively

Comment: @JacobSchneider That's interesting, mind if I add it to my answer? I don't think it uses the API, instead it uses the UI to change the DNS settings, am I correct?

Comment: Making use of APIs in that way is fun

Comment: Snooping through its source code, I can see the use of beautiful soup, a clear indication that it uses the ui